# Remove from text words made of different symbols

Tags: c#

Hey guys im new here and i need to make my program to remove all words from txt file which are made of different symbols. I dont even know where to start.
PS. 
Sorry for my English. :)

```
public int Imti(char sim)
{
    return Rn[sim];
}
public void kiek()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < eil.Length; i++)
    {
        if (('a' <= eil[i] && eil[i] <= 'z') || ('A' <= eil[i] && eil[i] <= 'Z'))
            Rn[eil[i]]++;
    }
}
static void Spausdinti(string fv, RaidziuDazniai eil)
{
    using (var fr = File.CreateText(fv))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fv, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));

        for (char sim = 'a'; sim <= 'z'; sim++)
            fr.WriteLine("{0,3:c} {1,4:d}   |{2,3:c} {3,4:d}", sim, eil.Imti(sim), Char.ToUpper(sim), eil.Imti(Char.ToUpper(sim)));
    }
}
static void Dazniai(string fv, RaidziuDazniai eil)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fv))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            eil.eil = line;
            eil.kiek();
        }
    }
```

this is what i made before

**To clarify what the OP is asking: He wants to remove words from a string that have the same character 2 or more times. For example, "test" should be removed because it has 2 t's.**

Comment: We need to see your text, input and expected output and a **clearly defined problem you're having**. "I don't know where to start" is far too ambiguous

Comment: What are *different symbols*? What is *word*? - symbols between spaces? Could you, please, provide some *examples* of words which should be removed (and why) as well as words should be spared

Comment: it could be letters or numbers for example 'word' this word should be removed but word 'mom' not because it has 2 same letters words cant be spared all possible ways

Comment: Now I think I get it. By "Symbols" you mean "characters" as in "remove all words made up from unique characters"?

Comment: compare the length of your word with the length of the distinct set of it's chars `word.Length == word.Distinct ().Count ()`

Comment: The text file for the text. Words from the line to the next line does not set. Isolating known.
Remove from the text words consisting only of different characters.
this is my task maybe u will understand this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt this here to your needs, output holds all distinct character words:

```
const string test =
"this is a test text consisting of various words where some consist of unique characters only while others have duplicates in them.";

var words = test.Split(' ');
var output=new List<string>();
foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (word.Distinct().Count() == word.Length) // word contains distinct characters only
    {
        output.Add(word);
    }
}
Debug.Print(string.Join(" ",output));
```

Comment: you don't need to use `ToCharArray` a string is already an `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: @Sehnsucht Tru dat. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will find words with a duplicate character and remove them from the string:

```
var input = "OK WORDS: \"box, super, list, word\", BAD WORDS: \"mom, test, accept, less\"?";
var regex = new Regex(@"\b[\w\d]*([\w\d])[\w\d]*\1[\w\d]*\b");
var output = regex.Replace(input, string.Empty);
```

Comment: No, I need to remove word if its made of 2 or more same letters. If i undestand everything i should just decompose words ind check if it has same letters or Im wrong about that?

Comment: So these words are ok "box, super, list, word", and these words should be removed "mom, test, accept, less"?

Comment: Updated to match that criteria.

Comment: You can simplify the regex to this if you don't care about numbers: `Regex(@"\b[\w]*([\w])[\w]*\1[\w]*\b")`